# Installing ada libraries from github -- to keep getting file not found error

Tags: ada, spark-ada

This is such a noddy question, but I'm struggling to particularly install `libadalang` which (to avoid X-Y problem) came from me having a working Gnatstudio, installing ada webserver, then I couldn't start Gnatstudio as it required `libadalang.so`. So I tried to install `libadalang` and
am currently getting failures of the form

`libadalang-iterators-extensions.ads:29:29: file "langkit_support-symbols-precomputed.ads" not found`

So I've spammed my `/opt/GNAT/2020` with installing `langkit` everywhere that looks likely.

```
./lib/langkit_support
./lib/lib/langkit_support
./lib/include/langkit_support
./include/langkit_support
```

And still the installer for `libadalang` doesn't work.

Clearly something going on with paths here that I'm not getting. Can anyone provide any information on how paths are supposed to work as I need to install a number of other ada and SPARK-ada libraries from github and I want to do it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, the simplest way to restore GNAT Studio is to delete everything and reinstall. The GNAT Studio has its-own copy of libadalang/langkit. Look for

```
<install-path>/lib/gnatstudio/libadalang.so
<install-path>/lib/gnatstudio/liblangkit_support.so
```

When you install a developer version of libadalang you will get another copy of these files. They could have a different version.

I would suggest you to install GNAT Studio into a dedicated directory and make sure you launch it with a shell script from the bin (`bin/gnatstudio`). This way it shouldn't be affected by any other installed libraries.

Installing AWS shouldn't break GNAT Studio installation. If you know how to reproduce, please report to AdaCore.

Comment: You are correct -- libadalang.so is in the /path/lib/gnatstudio/ directory. So will reinstail and hope that in some way fixes things. Would you mind also illustrating the correct path to install to if my GNAT is installed in /opt/GNAT/ please?